# Delphi 11.2. All buttons have changed

Tags: android, delphi

After updating my Android App to Delphi 11.2, all the standard buttons have changed.
Previousely they where blue, with a faint lighter blue border.
Now all buttons (including 'Tab' buttons) have a bright light-blue *double* border, and it looks ridiculous.

My buttons are all default, and have an empty 'StyleName'. Setting this to "buttonstyle" has no effect.
I cannot update my App now.

Why do these things happen?
How do I fix this?

Bart

Comment: Did you use a StyleBook ? 
If not, I suggest you to add one

Comment: Yes, always had a StyleBook on the main form.

Comment: Which one did you use ?
Take care to load style for 11.2, I had some errors with old ones

Comment: When I remove the existing StyleBook, which I added many years ago, everything goes white. I had a black background and blue buttons. When I load a new Stylebook, this does not change. I do not have any FILE anywhere with a Style. I have no idea where the Style data is stored. When I try to add a new Style for Android, I get a huge pulldown-list which is completely empty, and there is nothing I can select. I have no idea how to re-create the Style from the original Stylebook. I had to go back to a backup, to get my App colors back.

Comment: Even more weird, is that when I compare the new and backup directory trees, the ONLY item which has changed is the entry "stylebook1" in the main unit. Absolutely nothing else is changed. Still, my Style is gone. This must mean it is stored somewhere else, and NOT in my actual directory tree for the entire App. Is this some very old Bug, where it would have stored its data somewhere else, lacking a specific filename for the Stylebook??